# Auto logout inactive users

Tags: macos, launchd, automation, cron

My iMac is set up using Parental Controls to limit how long my kids can use it.

When their time is up, they are no longer able to use the iMac.  However, their accounts are not logged out, and whatever they were doing continues to run.

They like to play Roblox, and I have found that a single Roblox session continuing to run hogs a lot of CPU and slows everything down.  I fix this by killing the loginwindow process for each child when I realise this is happening.

I'd like to set my Mac up so *select* accounts are automatically logged out after a period of inactivity, so the Roblox issue is resolved for me.  I saw [an answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/374321/24368) that achieved this using `cron`.  However, adding scripts to /bin and /sbin (and /usr/local/bin) is no longer straightforward due to security changes.

[StackOverflow had a suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133425/246433) for running scheduled scripts using `launchd` which looks nicer and more the Mac way.

Has anyone managed to do this in recent versions of MacOS (I'm on Mojave) using either of the above methods or something else?

Note I don't want my account to get logged out after a period of inactivity - so the Autologout option in **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General > Advanced** doesn't meet my needs.